# "is" operator compile-time warning

Tags: c#, warnings

From the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> The is keyword causes a compile-time warning if the expression is
>   known to always be true.

I tried to create an example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void method(MyClass c)
    {
        if (c is MyClass)
        {
            //...
        }

        if (c is Object)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't get any warnings. Why?

Can someone show me an example where I get a warning (because the expression is always true)?

It works for false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `is` operator will return false if the value is `null`, so if you call `method(null)` it would not enter either `if`-block.

However, if `MyClass` were actually a `struct` (i.e. not nullable), this would produce a warning.

Comment: Just to add details [from the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx): An `is` expression evaluates to true **if the provided expression is non-null**, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown